# How to set namespace and item expiration for a symfony5 redis cachepool

Tags: caching, redis, symfony5

I try to configure two cache pools in my Synfony5 app to use a certain namespace and set a default expiration date for the items. After trying for the umpteenth time the umteenth variation I get the feeling that my configuration is going in circles.

What I understood so far:
**In the constructor** of the RedisAdapter you can set the namespace and the default expiration time
**In the createConnection method** you set the url of your redis server.

However the constructor of the RedisAdapter seems to already need a redis client (= redis connection?)
RedisAdapter:

```
/**
 * @param \Redis|\RedisArray|\RedisCluster|\Predis\ClientInterface $redisClient     The redis client
 * @param string                                                   $namespace       The default namespace
 * @param int                                                      $defaultLifetime The default lifetime
 */
public function __construct($redisClient, string $namespace = '', int $defaultLifetime = 0, MarshallerInterface $marshaller = null)
{
    $this->init($redisClient, $namespace, $defaultLifetime, $marshaller);
}
```

**How can I inject my namespaces and defaultLifetimes into the RedisAdapter?**

What I tried so far:
cache.yaml:

```
framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            cache.sap:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
                provider: app.service.puc_sap_redis_adapter
            cache.pers:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
                provider: app.service.puc_pers_redis_adapter
```

services.yaml:

```
app.my_redis_adapter:
    class: 'Redis'
    factory: ['Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter', 'createConnection']
    arguments:
        - 'redis://%env(string:REDIS_URL)%:%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%'
        - { retry_interval: 2, timeout: 5 }

app.service.puc_sap_redis_adapter:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter
    arguments:
        $redisClient: '@app.my_redis_adapter'
        $namespace: 'sapData'
        $defaultLifetime: '%env(SAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT)%'

app.service.puc_pers_redis_adapter:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter
    arguments:
        $redisClient: '@app.my_redis_adapter'
        $namespace: 'persData'
        $defaultLifetime: '%env(CACHE_TIMEOUT)%'
```

This gets me the error message:

```
line: 62, 
file: "/var/www/vendor/symfony/cache/Traits/RedisTrait.php", 
message: "\"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Traits\\RedisTrait::init()\" 
expects parameter 1 to be Redis, RedisArray, RedisCluster or Predis\\ClientInterface, 
\"Symfony\\Component\\Cache\\Adapter\\RedisAdapter\" given."
```

**How can I configure the namespaces and expiration time for my two cache pools?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After several days of blood, sweat and tears I leave this here so nobody else will have to experience this deep desperation.

This is how it works. You will need no extra class "just" this nifty cache.yaml in the folder for your environment:

```
framework:
    cache:
        pools:
            cache.sap:
                adapter: app.cache.adapter.sap_redis  # custom namespace and item expiration defined there
                provider: app.cache.custom_redis_provider # Which server connection should be used
            cache.pers:
                adapter: app.cache.adapter.pers_redis # custom namespace and item expiration defined there
                provider: app.cache.custom_redis_provider # Which server connection should be used

services:
    app.cache.custom_redis_provider: # this defines our connection to the redis server
        class: \Redis
        factory: ['Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\RedisAdapter', 'createConnection']
        arguments:
            - 'redis://%env(string:REDIS_URL)%:%env(int:REDIS_PORT)%' # this defines the url to the redis server. "redis" up front is mandatory
            - { retry_interval: 2, timeout: 5 }  # defines number of connection retries and connection timeout (not item expiration!)

    app.cache.adapter.sap_redis: # here we pass namespace and expiration timeout into the constructor of the redis adapter
        parent: 'cache.adapter.redis'
        tags:
            - { name: 'cache.pool', namespace: 'sapData', default_lifetime: '%env(int:SAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT)%' }

    app.cache.adapter.pers_redis: # here we pass a different namespace and expiration timeout into the constructor of the redis adapter
        parent: 'cache.adapter.redis'
        tags:
            - { name: 'cache.pool', namespace: 'persData', default_lifetime: '%env(int:CACHE_TIMEOUT)%' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set those parameters within the usual [cache-pool configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#creating-custom-namespaced-pools).

```yaml
framework:
    cache:
        default_memcached_provider: 'memcached://localhost'
        # could also replace with 
        # default_redis_provider: 'redis://localhost' # or '%env(REDIS_DSN)%'

        pools:
            # creates a "custom_thing.cache" service
            # autowireable via "CacheInterface $customThingCache"
            # uses the "app" cache configuration
            custom_thing.cache:
                adapter: cache.app 

            # creates a "my_cache_pool" service
            # autowireable via "CacheInterface $myCachePool"
            my_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.filesystem

            # uses the default_memcached_provider from above
            acme.cache:
                adapter: cache.adapter.memcached

            # control adapter's configuration - customised provider adaptor & DSN
            foobar.cache:
                adapter: cache.adapter.memcached
                provider: 'memcached://user:password@example.com'

            # uses the "foobar.cache" pool as its backend but controls
            # the lifetime and (like all pools) has a separate cache namespace
            short_cache:
                adapter: foobar.cache
                default_lifetime: 60
```

The page (linked above) goes on to say how to tag a service for a specific namespace, but the various configured pools already have one set by default:

> Each pool manages a set of independent cache keys: keys from different pools never collide, even if they share the same backend. This is achieved by prefixing keys with a namespace that’s generated by hashing the name of the pool, the name of the compiled container class and a configurable seed that defaults to the project directory.

Comment: yes they have a random key set by default. Therefore you cannot know which one it is. In my case a thirdparty application was writing the info into the redis server and my application was reading them. 

So if you want to use the cache pool system and not write you own redis cache class you have to be able to force your app to use a certain namespace.